# Why Java uses one past index for upper bound in string operations?

Tags: java, string

In String functions like substring()

```
"hello".substring(0, 3)
```

returns hel

whereas 0-3 index includes hell

and in regex Matcher's end() method

```
mat = Pattern.compile("test").matcher("test");
mat.find();
System.out.println(mat.end());
```

returns 4 
whereas first match ends at index 3

I'm just curious about why java works in this way

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For one thing, because the endpoint is excluded, `s.substring(i,j)` has length `j-i` (which is intuitively correct).

For another, `s.substring(i,j) + s.substring(j,k)` is equal to `s.substring(i,k)` (for sensible values of `i`, `j` and `k`).

Also, `s.substring(0, s.length())` describes the whole of `s`, as it should, because the endpoint is excluded.

If the endpoint was included, you'd be continually having to remember to add or subtract one from things in order to make stuff work.

[`Matcher.end()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#end()) is consistent with these: start-inclusive, end-exclusive, so `s.substring(m.start(), m.end())` gives you the substring matched.

Comment: What is the reasoning for `matcher.end()` to return the index of the last matched character + 1 then? (I think that is what the question was all about)

Comment: Because `matcher.end()` is consistent with `substring` and with range-specifying in general: start-inclusive, end-exclusive.

Comment: `matcher.end()` returns "The offset *after* the last character matched" which sounds like it is inclusive. If it were exclusive, wouldn't it just return the index of the last matched character instead?

Comment: @Kapep No, it wouldn't. It is exclusive because the matched range _excludes_ the endpoint. Therefore the endpoint (`m.end()`) is _after_ the last character matched.

Comment: Ok I guess it just depends on how you define the endoint of a match. The range from `start()` to `end()` includes the index of the last matched character. It excludes the index of the character after the last matched character.